# Delete Route vs. Get - Methods for Rails Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, railstutorial.org, conventions

In Michael Hartel's Rails Tutorial he suggests creating the following route in oder to logout users:

```
delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

This seems to add some unnecessary legwork throughout the application, e.g., requiring links to include method: "delete". The following also works perfectly:

```
get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

Why is the convention to use the "delete" method and not simply "get"? Is there some hidden advantage?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons, two of the most vital:

- **Prevents inclusion of stray "destroy" links** (using `DELETE` in a destroy link means you have to explicitly define it)
- **Forms part of the ["resourceful" structure of HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)** (not as important, but if you want to create "real" web apps, it is vital for using the correct URL structure)

---

**Links**

The most important reason - for many - is the inclusion of stray "destroy" links in your views.

To *destroy* an object (which is what the `DELETE` method is meant to denote) is a serious endeavour -- you need to make sure the links you include are legitimate & cannot be confused.

Explicitly declaring `method: :delete` adds an immediate level of authorization to the links, enough to give you assurance the link is there for a reason.

The number of times I have seen people neglecting the `method` switch of their links is ridiculous -- imagine if you had the ability to *destroy* some data with such haphazard structure. You'd have so many mistakes in your code...

-

**Resources**

The second reason is more important - it retains the [*resourceful* nature of HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Technical_overview):

> **HTTP resources** are identified and located on the network by `uniform resource locators (URLs)`, using the `uniform resource identifier (URI)` schemes `http` and `https`. `URIs` and `hyperlinks` in `Hypertext Markup Language (HTML)` documents form inter-linked hypertext documents.

Simply, the real structure of HTTP (the protocol which powers the "web") is such that you're *meant* to load *resources* through it.

[This video](https://youtu.be/j4cN_q3NX9c?t=530) explains it quite well:
[image]

These resources are meant to be located through specific `urls`, and if you think about it properly, only have a certain number of permutations which would allow the resource to be managed.

Indeed, when it comes to Rails, many engage with the *resourceful* nature of the web for the first time, hence questions like this. I didn't know about it until working with Rails... which is why it's so important to understand *why* [this type of setup](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) works so well:

[image]

The above shows what happens when using the rails `resources` helper (which I'd strongly recommend you use):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :sessions, path: "", path_names: { destroy: "logout" }
```

This will create a set of "resourceful" links (as above). These links basically denote how you should handle the *resources* on your app, of course placing the `DELETE` method with the `destroy` action.

You don't have to use `DELETE` but it certainly makes your application more versatile!

Answer (score 0):

Get is different in DELETE Request.

GET - Requests data from a specified resource
DELETE  Deletes the specified resource

See [HTTP REQUEST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

The main target is to make meaningful/semantic http requests.

since it corresponds to deleting `session` object via `destroy` action; `RESTful` recommends to use semantic HTTP verb `delete` rather than `get`. Moreover, Rails maps `delete` verb to `destroy` action by default.

Since you are not getting anything after you delete session rather you are redirected to somewhere else; so it is recommended to make `AJAX` calls with `delete` method.

[image]

For more info see this
https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide